# Strange results with Razor if statement

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view that displays different buttons under certain circumstances. However, when I change this if statement I get different results even though I believe these if statements technically do the same thing. How could I fix this so the if statement is fully functional? If needed, I'll post up the entire view as well. Just please request it in comments!

Basically, when I toggle my database values to toggle "ButtonStatus" between 0 and 1, I want to switch what I want to do in the if statement.

My partial view:

```
    @if(ViewBag.ButtonStatus != 0) 
    {
            ....
            //display 1 or 2 buttons
            ....
            ....
    }
    else {
            ....
            // do not display buttons
            ....
    }
```

Currently with this if statement, display 1 or 2 buttons works fine (ButtonStatus = 1). However, when ButtonStatus = 0, 2 buttons are still being displayed. Meaning, the logic never goes into the else part of the if statement. I even put an alert inside the GrabGhCsStatus function and the alert goes off =/

When I change the partial view to

My changed partial view:

```
    @if(ViewBag.ButtonStatus == 1) 
    {
            ....
            //display 1 or 2 buttons
            ....
            ....
    }
    else {
            ....
            // do not display buttons
            ....
    }
```

None of the buttons show even if ButtonStatus = 1. I put an alert in the else part of the if statement and the alert pops up. But when ButtonStatus = 1, the else portion should not be called

Controller:

```
        public class GhCsStatusController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewBag.CheckIfCsIsRunning = GhCsStatusProvider.GetGhCsStatus()["CheckIfCsIsRunning"];
                ViewBag.CheckIfGhIsRunning = GhCsStatusProvider.GetGhCsStatus()["CheckIfGhIsRunning"];
                ViewBag.CsStatus = GhCsStatusProvider.GetGhCsStatus()["CsStatus"];
                ViewBag.GhStatus = GhCsStatusProvider.GetGhCsStatus()["GhStatus"];
                ViewBag.ButtonStatus = GhCsStatusProvider.GetGhCsStatus()["ButtonStatus"];

                return View();
            }
        }
```

Provider:

```
    public static class GhCsStatusProvider
        {
            public static Dictionary<string,int> GetGhCsStatus()
            {
                using (Entities db = new Entities())
                {
                    int ButtonStatus;

                    System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter CsOut = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("CsStatus", typeof(int));
                    System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter GhOut = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("GhStatus", typeof(int));
                    System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter CsRunValue = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("CSRunningValue", typeof(int));
                    System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter GhRunValue = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("GHRunningValue", typeof(int));
                    int r = db.proc_GhCsStatus(CsOut, GhOut, CsRunValue, GhRunValue);

                    Dictionary<string, int> Status = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                    Status.Add("CsStatus", (int)CsOut.Value) ;
                    Status.Add("GhStatus", (int)GhOut.Value);
                    Status.Add("CheckIfCsIsRunning", (int)CsRunValue.Value);
                    Status.Add("CheckIfGhIsRunning", (int)GhRunValue.Value);

                    if (Status["CheckIfCsIsRunning"] == 0 && Status["CheckIfGhIsRunning"] == 0)
                    {
                        ButtonStatus = 0;
                        Status.Add("ButtonStatus", ButtonStatus);            // 0 --> do not display
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Status["CheckIfCsIsRunning"] == 1 || Status["CheckIfGhIsRunning"] == 1)
                        {
                            ButtonStatus = 1;
                            Status.Add("ButtonStatus", ButtonStatus);            // 1 --> display
                        }
                    }

                    return Status;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try logging or just outputting `ViewBag.ButtonStatus` in your View. I'm guessing it isn't being set in your provider and the value is neither `0` or `1`.

Comment: I created a view that outputs ButtonStatus in JSON and it does toggle between 0 and 1 in that view when I switch database values around =[

Comment: Have you debugged the code and stepped through it and checked all the values?

Comment: Well I checked the ButtonStatus first because that determines where in the if statement occurs. The JSON value of the ButtonStatus I am getting in the testview I created is outputting correctly but when I pass it to the if statement view, it seems as though the if statement isn't working properly haha or like you said neither 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

try to convert the ViewBag.ButtonStatus to string in your View to see if it catches it. I'm not 100% sure but give it a shot. Something like this... @if(ViewBag.ButtonStatus.ToString() == "1")

Comment: the problem was fixed! i forgot what i did to fix it though haha sorry

Comment: but i think youre on the right track. I think the issue was due to some type issue